# C# Resorting an array in a unique way

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am wanting to create multiple arrays of ints(in C#). However they all must have a **unique** number in the index, which no other array has that number in that index. So let me try show you what I mean:

```
int[] ints_array = new int[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < ints_array.Count(); i++)
            ints_array[i] = i; 
//create a int array with 30 elems with each value increment by 1

        List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();
        for(int i = 0; i < ints_array.Count(); i++)
            arrayList.Add(ints_array[i]. //somehow sort the array here randomly so it will be unique
```

So I am trying to get the arrayList have 30 int[] arrays and each is sorted so no array **has the same int in the same index as another**.

Example:

```
arrayList[0] = {5,2,3,4,1,6,7,8,20,21... etc }
arrayList[1] = {1,0,5,2,9,10,29,15,29... etc }
arrayList[2] = {0,28,4,7,29,23,22,17... etc }
```

So would this possible to sort the array in this unique kind of way? If you need anymore information just ask and ill fill you in :)

Comment: Is this just a puzzle or is there a purpose?

Comment: How many arrays do you have? Is it the same number as the length of the array? Is this effectively sudoku-like?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes sorry, its the same as the length of the `ints_array` . And I guess it is sudoku-like!

Comment: So if you take the first array and rotate the values to the left one step you have a new valid array?

Comment: @DStanley This isnt just a puzzle, no. It's for part of the program I am currently developing.

Comment: What is the source of the ints? Can they be random? Do they have a fixed range? Are there any constraints on the int values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
List<int[]> arrayList = new List<int[]>();
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < ints_array.Length; i++)
{
     ints_array = ints_array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
     var isDuplicate = arrayList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(ints_array));
     if (isDuplicate)
     {
           while (arrayList.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(ints_array)))
           {
               ints_array = ints_array.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
           }
      }
      arrayList.Add(ints_array);
}
```

I think, this wouldn't be so efficient for bigger numbers than `30`.But in this case it shouldn't be a problem, in my machine it takes *7 milliseconds*.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick: http://prntscr.com/3cqg4y
Time doesnt really matter for this. Works a charm. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be easier to create the arrays iteratively using an offset pattern?

What I mean is that if you created the first array using 1-30 where 1 is at index 0, the next array could repeat this using 2-30 where 2 is at index 0 and then wrap back to 1 and start counting forward again as soon as you go past 30. It would be an easy and repeatable way to make sure no array shared the same value/index pair.

Comment: This works but all the arrays would have the exact same order, what if you want to have a different element order, yet still preserve unique indexing? Say, a swap.

Comment: @Vlad that is a valid point however the OP made no mention of that requirement. If it is something he needs he'll have to clarify and then this answer might not be an appropriate solution. As it stands I think it should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Jesse's idea would be best unless you needed a pure random pattern. In that case I would recommend generating a random number, checking all your previous arrays, and then placing it in an array if it did not match any other arrays current index. Otherwise, generate a new random number until you find a fresh one. Put that into a loop until all your arrays are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Use a matrix (2D-array). It is easier to handle than a list of arrays. Create a random number generator. Make sure to initialize it only once, otherwise random number generator may create bad random numbers, if created in too short time intervals, since the slow PC-clock might not have ticked in between. (The actual time is used as seed value).

```
private static Random random = new Random();
```

Create two helper arrays with shuffeled indexes for rows and columns:

```
    const int N = 30;

    int[] col = CreateUniqueShuffledValues(N);
    int[] row = CreateUniqueShuffledValues(N);
```

Then create and initialize the matrix by using the shuffeled row and column indexes:

```
    // Create matrix
    int[,] matrix = new int[N, N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            matrix[row[i], col[j]] = (i + j) % N;
        }
    }
```

The code uses these two helper methods:

```
private static int[] CreateUniqueShuffledValues(int n)
{
    // Create and initialize array with indexes.
    int[] array = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    // Shuffel array using one variant of Fisher–Yates shuffle
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int j = random.Next(i, n);
        Swap(array, i, j);
    }
    return array;
}

private static void Swap(int[] array, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int size = 10;

// generate table (no duplicates in rows, no duplicates in columns)
// 0 1 2
// 1 2 0
// 2 0 1
int[,] table = new int[size, size];
for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        table[y, x] = (y + x) % size;

// shuffle rows
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int y1 = rnd.Next(0, size);
    int y2 = rnd.Next(0, size);
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
    {
        int tmp = table[y1, x];
        table[y1, x] = table[y2, x];
        table[y2, x] = tmp;
    }
}

// shuffle columns
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    int x1 = rnd.Next(0, size);
    int x2 = rnd.Next(0, size);
    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
    {
        int tmp = table[y, x1];
        table[y, x1] = table[y, x2];
        table[y, x2] = tmp;
    }
}

// sample output
for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        Console.Write("{0} ", table[y, x]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```